# pyodbc.ProgrammingError:42000

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm making a web app in python dash and I'm getting this error,I'm kinda still a noob in the databses department so I'm a bit stuck.Can you give any hints?

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

This is my query:

```
def build_db_query_app7():
db_query_string = """SELECT NotificationLog.ID as 'ID',
                        DAY(Timestamp) as 'DAY',
                        MONTH(Timestamp) as 'MONTH',
                        NotificationLog.Duration,
                        DATEPART(WEEK, NotificationLog.Timestamp)-1 as 'Week Number'
                        FROM NotificationLog
                            BETWEEN ? AND ?"""
return db_query_string
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\denis.akvic\Desktop\flask\apps\app7.py", line 267, in fetch_the_downtime records = mssql_conn.execute_query(query_string, parameters, str(database)) File "C:\Users\denis.akvic\Desktop\flask\mssql_conn.py", line 63, in execute_query cursor.execute(query_string, parameters) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Where is you `WHERE`? In the above you attempt to alias your object `NotificationLog` with the reserved keyword `BETWEEN`. Voting to close as typographical error.

Comment: `... FROM NotificationLog WHERE some_column BETWEEN ...`

Comment: This question is answered in the comments above, but as a general tip I would recommend to first write your queries and test them using a database client. Only after confirming it works make the constants variable.

Comment: well when i run this query in my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 it gives me the right output,I will now try to put the WHERE  in the new query